# Water Pump Selection Guide for Robotic application

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

Actually, I'm attempting to construct an Arduino firefighting vehicle. I am aware that a pump would be necessary for it to function. My a few questions are listed below.

1. Despite my research on pumps, I was unable to locate exactly where the various types of pumps are employed in daily life. Please give me some links to references for it.
2. What additional mechanical part would be needed for robot , and why?
3. In order to direct my fluid precisely at the firespots, I also want to manage pump flow rate so that it can extinguish fire from a certain distance . Any suggestions on how I should control this pump  would be appreciated. I will use a DC pump, but I'm not sure what kind I need. such as do I require Peristaltic, Diapragham, or Centrifugal ?

Comment: Coventry climax made pumps for fire engines

Comment: Figure out the flow rate you need and where you are getting the water from.

Comment: I assume this is a small robot based on the fact that you're driving it with an arduino, but you never explicitly say that. How much water do you want, and how far do you want to throw it? A good  start for a small robot would be a windshield washer pump.

Comment: Nozzle design is also important.